# Why are the following 2 ’if' structures different on Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I wanted to look through a dataframe on Python, and replace `NaN` values in a specific column. I would like to understand what is the difference between these 2?

```py
if pd.isnull(coly):

if coly == np.NaN:
```

The first statement works, the second one doesn't even generate an error.

Comment: `==` doesn't work on nan.

Comment: `if` does not create a loop.

Comment: you need to use pd.isna .. and difference between that and pd.isnull, is that pd.isnull returns true for None

Answer (score 2):

1. coly == np.NaN  is always false. NaN is never equal to itself.
2. There are many different nans values (e.g. -numpy.nan).

To detect nan, you have to use `numpy.isnan` or other special nan-detect function (that looks into the binary structure of the value).